# Spark/Scala iterating two dataframes

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to `spark/scala` world. I have two sources of data

> 1. Traffic data which has URLs and hostnames
> 2. Attribute data which defines rules on the traffic urls. The rules are regex patterns to match the domain name. There could be one or many rules for one attribute-id.

If an URL meets criteria I have to assign an attribute-id. Each row in the traffic can match **zero or more attribute conditions**

A sample input
`traffic-data`

```
 visitor_id | url                      
 1000-abc10 | www.motor.com/index.html
 2000-fe30a | www.lifestyle.com/cooking/pasta.html
```

`attribute-data

```
attribute_id | rule                               | describtion
101          | motor.com, auto*.com, vehicles.com | "vehicles"
102          | motor.com                          | "auto site"
```

Expected output:

```
visitor_id  | attribute_id
1000-abc10  | 101
1000-abc10  | 202
```

I tried the following :

```
val traffic_df = spark.read.parquet(<traffic-path>).as[Traffic]
val attribute_df = spark.read.parquet(<attribute-path>).as[Attribute]

traffic_df.map(row => attribute_df.map(r => TrafficAttribute(row.visitor_id, r.attribute_id)))
```

Comment: You should add examples of your inputs, what output you want and what is not working with your code

Comment: I have added the input and output as suggested.

Comment: I could figure out a solution for my problem I have posted. To complete the loop I am here posting the code snippet below which worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

```
case class Traffic(visitor_id: String, page_url : String)
case class ConfigRow(attribute_id: String, rule: String, description: String)
case class OutputRow(visitor_id: String, attribute_id)

val configList = spark.sqlContext.read.json(<config-path>).as[ConfigRow].collect().toList
val trafficDF = spark.read.json(<traffic-path>).as[Traffic]

def determineAttributes(row: Traffic, configList: List[ConfigRow]): ListBuffer[String] = {
    val attributeList = new ListBuffer[String]
    for (c <- configList) {
      rule = c.rule;
      if (<rule matches>) attributeList += c.attribute_id
   }
   attributeList
}

for r = trafficDF.flatMap((row:Traffic) => {
   for (attributeId <- determineAttributes(row, configList)) yield {
      OutputRow(row.visitor_id, attributeId)
   }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a join with a special join condition on 2 datasets :

```
val joinCondition = $"a.url".contains($"b.rule")
var joinedDf = trafficDf.as('a).join(attributeDf.as('b),joinCondition)
joinedDf.show()

+----------+--------------------+------------+---------+-----------+
|visitor_id|                 url|attribute_id|     rule|describtion|
+----------+--------------------+------------+---------+-----------+
|1000-abc10|www.motor.com/ind...|         101|motor.com|   vehicles|
|1000-abc10|www.motor.com/ind...|         102|motor.com|  auto site|
+----------+--------------------+------------+---------+-----------+
```

then you can select the desired column with `joinedDf.select("visitor_id","attribute_id")`

Comment: Fabich, thanks for your reply really appreciate it. Actually, for brevity, I have added simple rules. It can have regex patterns I am not sure if this can be done with normal join condition.
Please see I have updated my input tables.